# How to use Media Queries inside a React Styled Components Keyframe?

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, css-animations, styled-components, keyframe

I can get media queries to work properly inside a regular `styled-components` component however when I attempted to use it in a `keyframe` (via import from `styled-components`) it does not seem to work at all.

Attempting to get a div to animate to a specific position, but have that end position change when the window is < 800px, I've attempted this:

```
import styled, { keyframes } from 'styled-components';

// ... further down ...

const slideAnim = keyframes`
  100% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 30px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 800px) {
    top: 70px;
    left: 50px;
    }

`;
```

I have also tried putting the media query in the `100%` block:

```
const slideAnim = keyframes`
  100% {
    top: 20px;
    left: 30px;

    @media (max-width: 800px) {
       top: 70px;
       left: 50px;
    }
  }
`;
```

I made a helpful interactive demonstration of what I am trying to achieve (problem code is at line 24):
https://codesandbox.io/embed/fragrant-star-m71ct

Feel free to change the `breakpoint` variable from 800 if you need to.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could take a different approach, where your `keyframes` animation is instead defined as a function like this:

```
const slideAnim = (top, left) => keyframes`
  100% {
    top: ${ top };
    left: ${ left };
  }  
`;
```

The function accepts input parameters that dictate the destination coordinates of `top` and `left` for that animation's final keyframe.

In your stlyed component (ie `Box1`), you'd then invoke `slideAnim()` with specific coordinates to each breakpoint, to achieve different animation behavior per breakpoint:

```
/*
Declare responsive styling in the Box1 component, where destination
coordinates are specified for the animate on a per-breakpoint-basis
*/
const Box1 = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
  top: 80px;

  &.slide {

    animation: ${slideAnim('20px', '30px')} 0.4s ease-in-out forwards;

    @media (max-width: ${breakpoint}px) {
      animation: ${slideAnim('70px', '50px')} 0.4s ease-in-out forwards;
    }    
  }
`;
```

In summary, the idea is to shift the responsive styling into your styled component (ie `Box1`), while defining a reusable function that contains the common/shared `keyframes` for each responsive breakpoint.

Here's [a working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-leaf-elytp) - hope that helps!

Comment: Oh sweet! I wasn't even aware that I could define a styled component as a function in this way. This solves my problem and is even better than what I was trying to do since I can flexibly reuse that function for multiple animations (which I need to do for my real project). Thanks!

Comment: @damon hey you're welcome - yep, the styled components library is pretty amazing :)

Comment: This is a different approach but this thing can be solved by normal approach. Cool anyways. A different approach is always good.

Answer (score 5):

A more developed approach to use media queries with styled-components

firstly we define the screen size for each device:

```js
const size = {
  mobile: "320px",
  tablet: "768px",
  laptop: "1024px",
  desktop: "2560px",
}
```

then we use `css` imported from `styled-components` to address media queries in relevant constants for each device

```js
export const mobile = (inner) => css`
  @media (max-width: ${size.mobile}) {
    ${inner};
  }
`;
export const tablet= (inner) => css`
  @media (max-width: ${size.tablet}) {
    ${inner};
  }
`;
export const desktop= (inner) => css`
  @media (max-width: ${size.desktop}) {
    ${inner};
  }
`;
export const laptop= (inner) => css`
  @media (max-width: ${size.laptop}) {
    ${inner};
  }
`;
```

now lets say you are creating a styled div and you want to use media queries it. and based on the accepted answer to use keyframes

```js
const slideAnim = (top, left) => keyframes`
  100% {
    top: ${ top };
    left: ${ left };
  }  
`;
const StyledDiv= styled.div`

 /* ...css */

    animation: ${slideAnim('20px', '30px')} 0.4s ease-in-out forwards;

   ${mobile(css`
     width:300px;
     animation: ${slideAnim('10px', '20px')} 0.1s ease-in-out forwards;
      /* ...css */
   `)};

   ${tablet(css`
     width:500px;
      /* ...css */
   `)};

    /*... and so on */
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keyframes outside of all blocks. eg:

```
import { IconButton} from "@material-ui/core"; 
const CloseButton = styled(IconButton)`
  padding: 3px !important;
  outline: none;


  @media only screen and (min-width: 728px) {
    padding: 4px !important;
    margin:0
  }
`;
```

Comment: The only problem is that you are using `@media` inside  `100%` block